# html definition list on same line with variable dt size

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a dl with the dt and dd on the same line and with the following additional requirements:

- dt and dd are shown on the same line
- width of all the dt's are the same and should be the same as the with of the longest content (in this example 'location', but it should also be working with different content)
- width of dd is the rest of the available space
- space between dt and dd is 1em
- vertical margin between dl and next dd is 1em

My code so far:

```css
dt {
    margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
dd {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>Date:</dt>
    <dd>wed 6 january 2017</dd>
    <dt>Location:</dt>
    <dd>
        Champ de Mars<br/>5 Avenue Anatole France<br/>75007 Paris
    </dd>
    <dt>Info:</dt>
    <dd>
        The Eiffel Tower (/ˈaɪfəl ˈtaʊər/ eye-fəl towr; French: Tour Eiffel, pronounced: [tuʁ‿ɛfɛl] About this sound listen) is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed and built the tower.
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two partial solutions, one using flexbox, another using floats. No extra HTML, just yours. Both solutions are not for old browsers. Possible to get rid of `calc()` by putting the horizontal spacing inside elements, not outside (margin), as it is now.

Well, and the main thing: sorry, but the widths are static — 20% for `dt`, 80%-1em for `dd`. To make it work like you need, taking the max width of all `dt` elements, you'll have to use JavaScript and count widths of `dt` and `dd`. Or switch to ye olde table layout, which would literally solve the whole thing. As far as I know.

```css
dl.using-flex{ display: flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.using-flex dt { flex-basis:20%; }
.using-flex dd { flex-basis: calc(80% - 1em); }


dl.using-floats{ overflow:hidden; /* for clearfix */}
.using-floats dt{ float:left; width:20%; clear:left;}
.using-floats dd{ float:left; width:calc(80% - 1em); }

dt, dd{ margin:0 0 1em; }
dd{ margin-left:1em; }
```

```html
<h2>Using flexbox</h2>
<dl class="using-flex">
    <dt>Date:</dt>
    <dd>wed 6 january 2017</dd>
    <dt>Location:</dt>
    <dd>
        Champ de Mars<br/>5 Avenue Anatole France<br/>75007 Paris
    </dd>
    <dt>Info:</dt>
    <dd>
        The Eiffel Tower (/ˈaɪfəl ˈtaʊər/ eye-fəl towr; French: Tour Eiffel, pronounced: [tuʁ‿ɛfɛl] About this sound listen) is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed and built the tower.
    </dd>
</dl>

<h2>Using floats</h2>
<dl class="using-floats">
    <dt>Date:</dt>
    <dd>wed 6 january 2017</dd>
    <dt>Location:</dt>
    <dd>
        Champ de Mars<br/>5 Avenue Anatole France<br/>75007 Paris
    </dd>
    <dt>Info:</dt>
    <dd>
        The Eiffel Tower (/ˈaɪfəl ˈtaʊər/ eye-fəl towr; French: Tour Eiffel, pronounced: [tuʁ‿ɛfɛl] About this sound listen) is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed and built the tower.
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: To use the table layout I need to add additional elements to the html right? To create rows.

Comment: Yes. Fully switch to a table with tr for rows and td instead of dt and dd.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `float: left` on `dt` and `dd`, `clear: both` on `dt` and percentage widths on both (adjust values to your needs)

(unaltered HTML)

```css
dt {
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 15%
}
dd {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Date:</dt>
  <dd>wed 6 january 2017</dd>
  <dt>Location:</dt>
  <dd>
    Champ de Mars
    <br/>5 Avenue Anatole France
    <br/>75007 Paris
  </dd>
  <dt>Info:</dt>
  <dd>
    The Eiffel Tower (/ˈaɪfəl ˈtaʊər/ eye-fəl towr; French: Tour Eiffel, pronounced: [tuʁ‿ɛfɛl] About this sound listen) is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed
    and built the tower.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's not possible to do it without the width?

Comment: if you erase the width, you'll see that the very last container goes under the second-to last, because it has enough content to fill the whole width of the window/parent. So you have to limit the width, otherwise it spreads out over the whole width. You could use a table instead, but that's completely different regarding the HTML.